# Danfoss ac drive output voltage unbalance

Tags: transistors, capacitor, mosfet, resistors, inductor

i have a problem with danfoss ac drive, i replace the output igbt module with new one, when power the drive the output voltage not balance and the input voltage balance L1: 400v,L2:400v,L3:400v, output voltage U:172,V:100,w:230, the speed reference is on 35HZ, and no any error code display. please advise what to do

Comment: switch off and find someone with experience.

Answer (score 0):

The input line balance has nothing to do with the output balance. If you are measuring the voltage without the motor connected, check the connections and try with the motor connected. Start with the speed reference set at 5 or 10 Hz. Check for motor current imbalance. If you have imbalance with the motor connected, check the connections and the gate signals. Check to see if the manual has a troubleshooting guide. Ask Danfoss or the supplier.